# In SparkR, how can we add a new column based on logical operations on an existing column?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I can easily do this

```
employees$salarynew = employees$Salary * 2
employees$sale_chance <- (employee$Salary > 2000)
```

But if I want something like this

```
employees$sale_chance_1 <-  if (employees$Salary > 2000) 'high'  else 'low'
```

It gives error

```
Error in if (employees$Salary > 2000) "high" else "low" : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

This also gives same error

```
emp1 <- withColumn(employees, "sale_prob", {if (employees$Salary > 2000) 'high' else 'low'})
```

Comment: shouldn't it be like `ifelse(employees$Salary > 2000, 'high',  'low')`

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldn't it be like this `ifelse(employees$Salary > 2000, 'high', 'low')`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment

```
emp$sale = ifelse(emp$Salary > 2000, 'high', 'low')
```

Also, this works for more complex expressions

```
emp1 <- selectExpr(emp, "case Salary>2000 when TRUE then 'high' else 'low' end as sale_prob")
```